# PHP Redirect After URL Entered Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am developing a news media website, and I am having a single issue...

When a user clicks on a news article, it links to [www.mydomain.com/news/article-name/](http://www.mydomain.com/news/article-name/)

However, if you remove the article name in the URL, resulting in [www.mydomain.com/news/](http://www.mydomain.com/news/) the PHP throws errors. I have turned off the PHP errors, and when I do, the website, of course, removes the article texts, article content, and the image.

When errors are turned on, and the URL is changed, I get the following error on the page... "Notice: Undefined index: news_id"

My question is this... ...how do I redirect a user back to my homepage if they purposely or accidentally change the URL?

My code is this...

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');

// Preventing the direct access of this page.
if(!isset($_REQUEST['slug']))
{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}

// Getting the news detailed data from the news id
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_slug=?");
$statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['slug']));
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $news_title = $row['news_title'];
    $news_content = $row['news_content'];
    $news_date = $row['news_date'];
    $publisher = $row['publisher'];
    $source = $row['source'];
    $photo = $row['photo'];
}

// Update data for view count for this news page
// Getting current view count
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_slug=?");
$statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['slug']));
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
    $current_total_view = $row['total_view'];
}
$updated_total_view = $current_total_view+1;

// Updating database for view count
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_news SET total_view=? WHERE news_slug=?");
$statement->execute(array($updated_total_view,$_REQUEST['slug']));
?>

<!-- Blog Start -->
```

I got it to working using the following

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');

// Preventing the direct access of this page.
if(!isset($_REQUEST['slug']))
{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Check the news slug is valid or not.
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_slug=? AND status=?");
    $statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['slug'],'Published'));
    $total = $statement->rowCount();
    if( $total == 0 )
    {
        header('location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the exact error message in the question.

Comment: Edited it, but basically the error states, "Notice: Undefined index: news_id"

Comment: Where is news_id in this script? My guess is you need to look at the $statement object to see if any rows were affected. Then you can decide if you have a valid news_slug.

Answer (score 0):

extract Id from URL, if that id does not match from your database then use redirection